# How to find the limit of a two variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Plugging in (0, 0) leads to an indeterminate form (zero divided by zero).
Would the only way to approach this problem be through multiplying by the conjugate $\dfrac{(x^2 - y^2)^{3/2}}{(x^2 - y^2)^{3/2}}$?

Comment: Use finite expansions.

Comment: Using polar coordinates, you will find 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using polar coordinates we get $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{e^{r^4}-1}{r^3}$.

---

Then, since $$r=0\implies e^{r^4}-1=0=r^3$$
we can use L'Hopital rule: $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{e^{r^4}-1}{r^3}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dr}(e^{r^4}-1)}{\frac{d}{dr}r^3}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{4r^3e^{r^4}}{3r^2}$$

Comment: Actually I was thinking that but wouldn't that still lead to division by zero?

Answer (score 0):

set $$x=r\cos(\phi)$$ and $$y=r\sin(\phi)$$